# How to kill all child processes after parent process termination?

Tags: c, linux, process, posix, kill-process

I can kill a child process by the parent process. But what happen if a parent process has more than one child processes?

For example in below code , there are one parent process and 6 child processes. How to kill the other six child processes immediately after the parent process termination?

If you run this code, parent is terminated after 5 seconds.After that child process are terminated after another 5 seconds(totally 10 seconds).

But I want to kill 6 child processes immediately after the parent process termination.So parent and 6 child process should be terminated after 5 seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() 
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) // loop will run 6 times(there are 6 child processes.) 
    { 
        if(fork() == 0) 
        { 
            printf("Started [son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 

            sleep(10); //child waits 10 seconds,then it exitted.

            printf("Exitted [son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 

            exit(0); 
        } 
    } 

    //parent
    sleep(5);  //parent will wait 5 seconds than it will exit
    printf("Parent terminated\n");
    exit(0); //parent terminated.(how can I exit the the other 6 child processes too?)

}
```

Comment: Read manual for wait 2.

Comment: @purec I have already read, I don't want that parent wait childs.

Comment: OK... but it is a common practice when parent waits for children terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a probably more portable solution.

The `fork(2)` system call will return the PID of your child processes, you can store the PIDs, and then you can use `kill(2)` to send signal to the children and terminates them.

Notice that `SIGKILL` and `SIGTERM` signal may require some privileges of the parent process. If it doesn't have such privileges, you can send a `SIGCONT` to the child process, and modify the `SIGCONT` signal handler in your child process.

!!! Warning sign

From a signal handler using `exit()` is not safe. I've just checked the manual `man 7 signal` and found that it is not async safe. You can use `_exit`, `_Exit` or `abort`

Some pseudo code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
void* handler(int sig){
    _exit(0);
}
int main() 
{ 
    pid_t children[6];
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) // loop will run 6 times(there are 6 child processes.) 
    { 
        if((children[i] = fork()) == 0) 
        { 
            signal(SIGCONT,handler);
            printf("Started [son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 

            sleep(10); //child waits 10 seconds,then it exitted.

            printf("Exitted [son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 

            exit(0); 
        } 
    } 

    //parent
    sleep(5);  //parent will wait 5 seconds than it will exit
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        kill(children[I],SIGCONT);
    printf("Parent terminated\n");
    exit(0); //parent terminated.(how can I exit the the other 6 child processes too?)

}
```

Comment: If you can send one signal you should be able to send any.

Comment: @PSkocik Here's from kill(2) BSD manual. "For a process to have permission to send a signal to a process designated
     by pid, the real or effective user ID of the receiving process must match
     that of the sending process or the user must have appropriate privileges
     (such as given by a set-user-ID program or the user is the super-user).
     A single exception is the signal SIGCONT, which may always be sent to any
     descendant of the current process." Using SIGCONT is kind of a work around however (not quite semantically correct).

Comment: Now let me nitpic! :D `exit` isn't async-signal safe. You should be quitting with `_exit`. Nice answer anyway! +1d.

Comment: Well I just realized it before reading your post and rush to modify the answer haha, thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Thought up a POSIX way that doesn't require explicit kills.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can use `prctl` to request to be informed about the death of your parent by means of a signal (error-checking skipped).

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/prctl.h> //<<<<<<<<
#include <signal.h> //<<<<<<<<

int main() 
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) // loop will run 6 times(there are 6 child processes.) 
    { 
        if(fork() == 0) 
        { 
            prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM); //<<<<<<

            printf("Started [son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 

            sleep(2);

            printf("Exitted [son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 

            exit(0); 
        } 
    } 

    //parent
    sleep(1);
    printf("Parent terminated\n");
    exit(0);
   //<<< Linux auto-sends the deathsignal to all children

}
```

For a POSIX-compliant solution that doesn't require the parent process to explicitly kill its children when it dies, you can use async-IO pipes.

Async-IO relies on signals being sent on filedescriptor events. In this case you can get notified of a close-event caused by the kernel autoclosing the filedescriptors of a dying process just as long as you make sure the autoclose closes the last reference to the pipe-end file (error-checking skipped):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main()
{

    int pipes[6][2];
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) // loop will run 6 times(there are 6 child processes.)
    {
        pipe(pipes[i]); //create a pipe

        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            //get notified on an event on the read-end (we're aiming for the EOF event)
            fcntl(pipes[i][0],F_SETOWN,getpid()); 
            ioctl(pipes[i][0], FIOASYNC, &(int){1});

            for(int j=0; j<=i; j++) close(pipes[j][1]); //close all write-end ends so the refcount is 1 and the parent has the last ref

            printf("Started [son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid());

            sleep(2);

            printf("Exitted [son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid());

            exit(0);
        }
    }

    //parent
    sleep(1);
    printf("Parent terminated\n");
    exit(0); 
    //<<<this closes all the last write ends of the pipes and so the children will get notified with a signal 
    //the signal is SIGIO by default, whose default disposition is to kill the process (this can be changed by fcntl(fd,F_SETSIG,TheSignal))



}
```